# why does my new 2nd page show black, the code doesnt even work

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

So I just learnt how to made a new page in VSC and this is what I'm going through:

I made the new page and started coding in it just to test it

[image: click to see picture]

next I made the link so I can click it and see the new website, (which works.)

[image: click to see picture]

lastly after I code this is what my website looks like

[image: click to see picture]

Answer (score 0):

Use <!doctype>
And after, if you use a navbar, make all in only one folder, and in navbar you as use you can do like this:

[Name](/HowYouCalledPage)

Comment: where do i put <!doctype>

Comment: put <!doctype> at first tag in code: 
<!doctype> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<title> Name </title>
</head> 
<body> 
.
.
.
</body> 
</html>

Comment: well now since i put them in a folder, nothing shows up its all white . plz help

Comment: https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/6433/Wn55ZF.png

Comment: contact me at razvanpana20@gmail.com and i will help you